# Input mask and Validator for Date in QlineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I want to implement a QlineEdit in Qt which will have input mask of "00/00/0000"(mm/dd/yyyy) and also valid regular expression to check whether the user is entering a valid date or not.
Below is my code but it does not work.Can any body help me out?

```
    QString str1 = "(0[1-9]|1[012])";
    QString str2 = "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]3[01])";
    QString str3 = "(19|20)[0-9][0-9]";
    QRegExp ipRegex ("^" + str1
                     + "\\/" + str2
                     + "\\/" + str3
                     + "$");    

    QRegExpValidator *ipValidator = new QRegExpValidator(ipRegex, this);
    ui->lineEdit->setValidator(ipValidator);
    ui->lineEdit->setInputMask("00/00/0000");

    // Avoid having to move cursor before typing
    ui->lineEdit->setCursorPosition(0);
```

Comment: Why do not you use QDateEdit?

Comment: QDateEdit can be used but i want to do with QlIneEdit as few customizations are required in that QLineedit which cannot be achieved by QDateEdit

Comment: There seems to be a typo in `QString str2 = "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]3[01])";`. Shouldn't it be `"(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"`? (The last `|` was missing.) Btw. [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is a nice online reg-ex debugger.

Comment: According to [QRegExpValidator Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html#details): _the regexp is treated as if it begins with the start of string assertion (**^**) and ends with the end of string assertion (**$**);_ May be, it's an issue that you did this yourself as well. I could imagine that this could prevent the return of [Intermediate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#State-enum) which might be fatal to accept any input. (It's just a shot into blue - I haven't any experience with this stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

I offer you try this `code` :

```
// Set date validator for date lineedit
QRegExp R_date("(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|[1][0-2])/(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])");
QRegExpValidator *valida = new QRegExpValidator(R_date, this);
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(valida);

// Set place holder for date lineedit
ui->lineEdit->setPlaceholderText("Example : 21/05/2019");
```

It will be something like this :

[image]

Comment: Quick question, do you know why this works in QT but not on the website that was mentioned above [regex101](https://regex101.com/)? Is QT using a semi-unique way of regex formatting?

Comment: @bluejambo Try this `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|[1][0-2])\/(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])` in https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks, that works, do you by any chance know why QT doesn't need the backslash?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
QRegExp ipRegex ("(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]{1,2})/(0[1-9]|[12]{1,2})/(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])");
```

Comment: It would be good to explain why this works and why the OP's didn't.

Comment: This does not work for `dd:10:yyyy`. cannot set the `10` for month...